# How to create a query between two tables in an ASP.NET MVC web application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm having trouble creating a query between my tables 'utente' and 'indirizzo_residenza' that will do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM utente, indirizzo_residenza 
WHERE utente.idutente = indirizzo_residenza.idutente;
```

Right now I can only query one table or the other and return it as `OkObjectResult` object

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UtentesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly resdataContext _context;

        public UtentesController(resdataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Utentes/GetUtente
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUtente()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var address = _context.IndirizzoResidenza.FromSql("Select * from indirizzo_residenza");
            var users = _context.Utente.FromSql("SELECT * FROM utente");

            /* string q = "SELECT * from utente,indirizzo_residenza where utente.idutente=indirizzo_residenza=idutente;";
            */

            if (utente == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(users);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I manage to merge those two queries?

Thanks

Comment: Hey, I think `where utente.idutente=indirizzo_residenza=idutente` is not valid SQL unless it's syntax I have not come across before. Double check the desired SQL and update the question, please, then it will be easier to suggest the EF LINQ query to use.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not the recommended way of joining tables. So, I will propose you to use the INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT * 
FROM utente
INNER JOIN indirizzo_residenza 
ON utente.idutente = indirizzo_residenza.idutente;
```

Comment: Unfortunately i have alredy tried that and i'm always get an error: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR` .But i dont think the problem is the query itself, i think it's more in the code before the query since it will let me only get context from a table and noth both

Comment: I am not an expert in c# but it has no sense. As this problems happen, you may use a view instead, just adding CREATE VIEW <ViewName> AS to the query proposed and selecting from the View. It may look Naïf but hopefully it will work.